# ASP.NET, MVC, AngularJS - Add two notes per click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I cant get a loop to work properly. I am trying to set this up so when I click "Add note" it will first add two notes. Second time I click "Add note" it will add four notes and so on.

Like this, number of clicks:

> 1. []
> 2. [][]
> 3. [][][][]
> 4. [][][][][][][][]

Please take a look at this fiddle:

```
jsfiddle.net//VJ94U/1115/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? You needed the loop inside the click handler...

```
$scope.addNote = function() {       
    for (var i = 0; i < numAdds; i++) {
        $scope.itemsList.items1.push({});
        console.log('yay');
    }

    numAdds = numAdds * 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1116/

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you Paul.